# Web service return response for internal classes

Tags: spring-boot

I have a

```
Class A {
int a;
String  name;

}

Class B {
int id;
A objectA;

}
```

When I return the data of Object A from RestController it returns the null for Class B object even if it has the data inside.

Comment: Are you using `@JsonView` or `@JsonIgnore` anywhere ?

Comment: well then, i cant see any object of `Class B` defined in you `Class A`, may be that's the problem, could you post more code namely your controller, and both Classes, also check if `Class A` has data in it i.e. if its controller messing things up or `Class A object` does not have the data to begin with ?

Comment: I have checked it via log, it has the data

Comment: we might be able to help you out more if you could may be post your controller and classes ??

Comment: Thanks , for the help , the data was not injected properly.